# Include DLL in classic asp

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Is it possible to include a .net 3.5 framework DLL in classic asp?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's called creating a COM-Callable Wrapper.

Here is the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx)

The link that pops up for the Code Project article in Google is, surprisingly, not the better one. You'll want to check out this one: [Exposing .NET Components to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx) It's the best. Complete step-by-step tutorial.

It's worth noting that in a former life I had to develop and support a .NET application which was exposed to some COM-based integrations - and simply slapping `ComVisible` on my classes was putting me in a world of hurt. Pay attention to the author's explanation of the Interface Types in that article... that article is a gem.

Excerpt:

> Previously I was using AutoDual,
>   however Heath Stewart[^] pointed out
>   this was not the best method to use as
>   it can create version-related problems
>   in the long run. After reading a
>   little more I changed the code to use
>   ClassInterfaceType.None which forces
>   our class to gain access only through
>   our interface. This keeps everything
>   viable during changes to the class in
>   the future.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to expose this .NET assembly as a COM object. This could be done using the [regasm.exe utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx). For this the types that you need to use or the entire assembly must be decorated with the [`ComVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) attribute.

Then consume the COM object from classic ASP as you would with any normal COM object.